# bibliography style problem

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, packages, installing

Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_6RXQUqktUOajRvMnRoRFduODQ?usp=sharing) to a template that I want to use. It gives me the following error. How can I fix it? I am pretty new to LaTeX and do not know how to fix the error. I have downloaded the files and did not touch any file. I do not understand why this error occurs.
[image: error]

Comment: The error you have means you do not have a required field. You should look up which fields are required for that bibitem and check your file.

Comment: I have checked the file name it gives ( Newbib.bib line 731) it has   "%volume =       {11}", there is no file  name or somthing like that. it is in fact a reference  I did not know where the error exactly comes from

Comment: I did say check your bibliography file. If you would help us help you by providing some details, we could be more specific. Try uncommenting the volume field.

Comment: I have deleted the "%" from volume.. it gives me this :                         Input index file FinalVersionMaster.idx not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Comment: did it work for you the template, without any problem !!

Comment: The new error you get states what you should do next. Use the command `makeindex` on your file, meaning open a terminal, navigate to the correct folder, then run `makeindex` with the desired options on your file.

Comment: If you're new to LaTeX I won't recommend to use a big template. For starters use a minimum setup and learn the basics, later you can do the advanced stuff.

Comment: @Skillmon I have to use it am obliged to use it (for my master ) I have not the choice but I still not understand the configuration you have talked about .. I have used other templates ( from overleaf ..) it works fine but I have to change all my work on this one which does not even work for me

Comment: The template seems to use an indexing package which needs the backend `makeindex` (external program). So the package doesn't find its input file (`FinalVersionMaster.idx`) and prompts you to generate it using the extern program `makeindex` from a console (I don't know your OS, on Windows it's `cmd.exe`, on Linux the terminal of your choice).

Comment: Yeah windows 7, cmd.exe ! then, what am supposed to type ! ( I did not use it for the other template I used,  although it was also a big one .. it s strange !  )

Comment: I've taken a look at the template files, and there's only one word to describe their quality: AWFUL. The bib file (`newbib.bib`) is particularly bad. For instance, almost every single entry is assigned the `@article` type even though most of them should be assigned types such as `@book`, `@inproceedings`, and `@unpublished`. There are a few entries of type `@book`, but those are almost all wrong as well; most should be of type `@phdthesis` or `@techreport`. Trying to fix this mess is utterly hopeless and pointless. Don't waste your time. Really.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could give me the steps one by one to fix it (cmd.exe, then ... , .. )

Comment: @Mico unfortunately am obliged to  do so , I have to work with the template of my university it is obligatory :(

Comment: @magda -- Well, prepare yourself for a lot of misery and frustration. Incidentally, it's simply wrong, WRONG, to even try to use `%` as a comment character inside a bib entry. Thus, `%volume = ...` is bound to generate a nearly incomprehensible warning and/or error message. If one has to force BibTeX to disregard the `volume` field, one should change the field name to `xvolume` (or some other name that's not recognized by the bibliography style that's in use). Trying to comment out the field by prefixing a `%` character is utterly wrong.

Comment: @magda if you have to work with it, I guess the `newbib.bib` file's contents are not important for you (because they are already there before you worked with it). In this case print the contents to paper, delete the file, grab the printed paper, tear it up, burn the remains, distribute the ashes on a field at least 10 square kilometres big. After that create your own `*.bib`-file. Don't bother the `makeindex`-issue for the moment.

Comment: @Skillmon yes true ! there are not my references they are including in the template but am not using them okey great ! It will be simple like this thank you :)